# Position next and previous buttons on far right and left side of the Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I want to display the Highcharts ECG Graph with Position next and previous buttons on far right and left side of the chart so that user could move previous and next graph. I need to move previous and next graph by using > < image on far right and left. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You can add two buttons and use css styles for positions them. You need to catch click event and use setExtremes which allows to define range in xAxis.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes()

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8BHZ/

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 5);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply kindly post the sample code to add buttons in the highcharts?